# Split with multiple delimiters not working

Tags: java, split

For some reason my multi delimiter split is not working. Hope it just a syntax error.

This works, but I want to also split if it finds end date

```
String dateList[] = test.split("(?="+StartDate+")");
```

But this does not. Am I missing something?

```
String dateList[] = text.split("[(?="+StartDate+")(?="+EndDate+")]");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use "lookarounds" in a custom character class - they'd be just interpreted as characters of the class (and may not even compile the pattern properly if a malformed range is detected, e.g. with dangling `-` characters).

Use the `|` operator to alternate between `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

Something like:

```
String dateList[] = text.split("(?="+StartDate+"|"+EndDate+")");
```

**Notes**

- You also may want to invoke `Pattern.quote` on your start and end date values, in case they contain reserved characters.
- Java variable naming convention is `camelBack`, not `CamelCase`